# Android - keep javax.mail.Session reference across app life

Tags: java, android, email, session

here is my state I am working in app that authenticate user with our company email and  password

I created class to handle authenticate action , I need keep reference of my `session`  to be able to send email .

my tries :

1- save username , password and this is not secure.

2- save session via application instance but this remove when app closed.

any suggestion thank you in advance

```
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.util.ByteArrayDataSource;

/**
 * Created by mina on 8/28/2016.
 */
public class PMailSender {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String mailhost = "OURHOSt";
    private String stmp_port= "465";
    private Session session;

    static  {
        Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());
    }


    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public PMailSender(){

    }

    public PMailSender(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol" , "smtp");
        prop.setProperty("mail.host" , mailhost);
        prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait" , "false");

        prop.put("mail.smtp.auth" , "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.port" , stmp_port);
        prop.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port" , stmp_port);
        prop.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class" , "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback","false");

        session = Session.getInstance(prop , new PMailAuthenticator(username,password ));
        session.setDebug(true);

    }

    public boolean ValidateCredential(){

        try {
            Transport tr= session.getTransport();
            tr.connect(mailhost , username , password);
            Store mStore=session.getStore();
            tr.close();
        }catch (AuthenticationFailedException e){
            return false;
        }catch (MessagingException e){
            throw new RuntimeException("validate error " , e);
        }
        return true;

    }

    public synchronized  void SendMail (String subject , String body
    , String sender , String recipients ) throws MessagingException {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        DataHandler handler= new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes() , "text/plain"));
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setDataHandler(handler);

        if(recipients.indexOf(",") > 0)
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO ,InternetAddress.parse(recipients) );
        else
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO , new InternetAddress(recipients));

        Transport.send(message);

    }



}
```

Comment: You can save (serialize) session into disk cache when app is closing and restore it after app start.

Comment: thank you for answer but java mail api dont handle something like this , give me token to login later or something like this

Comment: Then there is only way - you need save encrypted login/pass and other properties. When app created you should restoring data and create new seassion.